# Return a new object from an existing object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ember.js, underscore.js

I have a Javascript object that resembles (the real object contains over 1,000 records):

```
var model = {
  "places": [
    {
      "title": "Centre Island Park",
      "id": 1800,
      "categories": [
        "park"
      ],
      "state": "ON",
      "country": "Canada",
      "neighborhood": "Downtown"
    },
    {
      "title": "Chagall Bistro",
      "id": 2914,
      "categories": [
        "lounge",
        "restaurant"
      ],
      "state": "NY",
      "country": "USA",
      "neighborhood": "Park Slope"
    },
    {
      "title": "Chai Ko Tapas",
      "id": 2365,
      "categories": [
        "restaurant"
      ],
      "state": "NJ",
      "country": "USA",
      "neighborhood": "North Jersey"
    },
    {
      "title": "Chatanooga",
      "id": 574,
      "categories": [
        "restaurant"
      ],
      "state": "NY",
      "country": "USA",
      "neighborhood": "Nassau"
    },
    {
      "title": "Chateau Steakhouse",
      "id": 2565,
      "categories": [
        "restaurant"
      ],
      "state": "NY",
      "country": "USA",
      "neighborhood": "Queens"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create a filter that will narrow down my results by state and category.
My first step was to create three new objects: `countries`, `states` and `categories`. I would then like to populate a select box for each of the object values and pass the selection on to my controller to use as a filter. My first step was to use vanilla Javascript to iterate through all the `places` and pull out all the **unique** state (and country, etc.) names and create a filter object with the following code:

```
var states = [];
model.forEach(function(place) {
    var state = place.state;
    var stateExists = states.some(function(element) {
        return element.name === state;
    });
    if(!stateExists && state && country) {
        states.push({name: state});
    }
});
```

The code was running extremely slow, so I switched to underscore.js:

```
var states = _.chain(model)
        .uniq(false, function(value) {return value.state})
        .sortBy(function(value) {return value.state})
        .filter(function(value) {return value.state})
        .map(function(value, key){
            return {name: value.state};
        })
        .value();
```

However, the code is still slow, and I prefer not have to many dependencies in my code.
Additionally, I'm already using Ember.js for this project, but I can't figure out the "Ember" way of doing this (if it exists).
Any suggestions / techniques to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried `groupBy`?

Comment: That actually looks good, @Bergi. Is there any way to do that without underscore?

Comment: Of course there is. Underscore is no magic, check out its plain JavaScript implementation. http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-35

Comment: OK, i tested it and it returned an object grouped by the key I gave it  `(place.state)`. However, I just need an array with the names of the states, countries, etc. Looks like groupBy won't do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I settled for an underscore.js solution. At least it didn't take too many lines of code!

```
var countries = [];
var states = [];
var categories = [];

model.forEach(function(place) {
    if(!_.contains(countries, place.country)) {
        countries.push(place.country);
    }
    if(!_.contains(states, place.state)) {
        states.push(place.state);
    }
    place.categories.forEach(function(category) {
        if(!_.contains(categories, category)) {
            categories.push(category);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions/techniques to do this more efficiently?

Perform your filtering and transformation on the back-end. Utilize REST endpoints to return your transformed and filtered objects to your controls via AJAX. A result set with 1000+ records appears too cumbersome for processing on the front-end, as you are currently attempting.

Comment: Thanks @wbennett. Unfortunately, I am trying to create a fully offline app (and eventually port it to Android, etc. with Cordova), so I assume I'm stuck with front-end frameworks(?).